# JPA @OneToMany with mySql and a third join table Without Unique key

Tags: mysql, jpa, one-to-many, unique-key

Hi in `@OneToMany` (mySql db) application I am want a separate Join table.
and implement like this

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long patientInfoId;

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "patient_health_issues", 
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "patient_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "health_issues_id") }
        )
private List<HealthIssues> healthIssues = new ArrayList<HealthIssues>();
```

and it will create a separate join table "patient_health_issues"
with "health_issues_id" as a unique key.
[image]

**where I don't want any unique key, is it possible, to control not to generate unique key.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this Situation it is not `@OneToMany` it is `@ManyToMany`